# Changing an image doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have downloaded a MVC project from an Open source and I am trying to make it my own.

I want to change images and add different things, new pages etc...

When I am changing an image in the content folder (for example the logo appearing at the top of the master page) it is always showing the old one.

If I change the name to logo1 for example I can see the new logo but as long as I am using logo the old logo is showing even if I changed the image.

Do you have an idea of what is going on!

Thanks

Comment: Have you cleared the cache in your browser?

Comment: Nate 
Thank you. I should have thought about that possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is caching the image, clear the cache and you should see the new image.